# How to remove custom tokens from mist?

Tags: mist, tokens, browsers, gui

[image: custom tokens]

In the MIST wallet (0.5.2) I somehow managed to create a Watch Token contract which was not correct and then it showed up like this: the one in the middle.
It is greyed out and I want to delete it, but unable to do so.
As you may be aware you can delete the other 2 (red and green ones shown here) when hovering the cursor over the icon which then turns into a recycle bin and you can then click and delete/remove it.
But the middle one is simply dead, nothing happens when moving over it.
How can I get it removed from there? 
BTW that UNICORNS token, I have no idea where that one came from? I did not create it, it popped there all by it's own :( ?? "scratching the top of my skull in confusion"

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Remove Greyed Out Token**

While you can hover your mouse over active Tokens and click on the trashcan icon to delete it, you will have to manually remove greyed out tokens.

In the Ethereum Wallet (Mist) menu, click on Develop -> Toggle Developer Tools -> Wallet UI. Alternatively, if you're using Parity (in your web browser), open up that browser's Developer Tools. Click on the Console tab.

- Then enter `Tokens.find().fetch()` to list your available tokens.
- Expand your list of Token objects and note the _id value of the token you want deleted.
- Enter the command `Tokens.remove({your Token _id value})` and press Enter. Your token then disappears from the Custom Tokens list.

[image]

Note that you can also remove Custom Contracts by using `CustomContracts.find().fetch()`, finding the _id of the Custom Contract, then entering the command `CustomContracts.remove({your Custom Contract _id})`.

The above information is based on on Ethereum Wallet 0.6.2 .

---

**Where Did The Unicorn Token Come From?**

You probably donated some ethers to the Ethereum Foundation - see [Donate to support development](https://www.ethereum.org/donate) . Under the section *Watch The Contract And Unicorns* are the instructions:

> First you might need to add the Unicorn Token to your watch list, as Unicorns are sometimes invisible. Scroll to the bottom and click Watch Token. Add the address 0x89205A3A3b2A69De6Dbf7f01ED13B2108B2c43e7 and the remaining information will be loaded automatically. Click Ok and your token will be added.

My Unicorn tokens automagically appeared out of the ether into my Ethereum Wallet after I made a donation to the Foundation - nice.

And if you have no more love for your Unicorns, send them to the [Unicorn Meat Grinder](https://gist.github.com/alexvandesande/eca0b87da89ab28fa50c), or send it my way as I am a closet Unicorn lover.

Answer (score 4):

Probably the easiest way to fix this is to delete the "Application Data" folder that you can find under the accounts-->backup menu.  This wont delete your accounts but make sure that you have your keystore folder backed up and the addresses of all your contracts.  You will then have to reimport the other tokens that you do want to watch.

Answer (score 2):

Hover over the identical of the token, it should change to a trash bin