# How do you delete/remove/hide contracts from Ethereum Wallet (aka mist)?

Tags: mist, wallets

I have tons of experimental contracts I created as part of doing tutorials which I no longer need. I know I can kill the contract (from https://www.ethereum.org/greeter tutorial) but that still leaves the contracts grayed out.

Answer (score 25):

Thats not so easy, if they are created on the testnet we gray them out. So you can't click on it and then on the trash can next to the name, on the contract page.

You would need to open the console (CMD/CTRL + ALT + i) and type:
`CustomContracts.find().fetch()`

Then look at the contract you want to remove and copy its `_id`.
Then type: `CustomContracts.remove('the_id_you_copied')`

Comment: You can do the same with `Tokens` or `CustomContracts`

Comment: This is also the answer for http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/2103/42 ?

Comment: I get `VM1547:2 Uncaught ReferenceError: Contracts is not defined(…)` in my console

Comment: When I click on the trash can, I have to confirm by giving the name of the contract. I do that, press Ok, the dialog goes away, but the contract remains. Trying the console commands fails as shown by @Makoto.

Comment: I fix the issue in the next version, you then just need to type "delete"

Comment: @Makoto, here is fix - https://github.com/ethereum/mist/issues/2891

Answer (score 9):

Or you can remove them all:

```
CustomContracts.find().fetch().map(
   function(m) { CustomContracts.remove(m._id);}
)
```

If you get an error saying "CustomContracts is not defined", be sure to open developer tools from the Contracts page via right clicking and selecting "Open Developer Tools," then navigating to the console.