# How to remove contracts and tokens from wallet.ethereum.org

Tags: wallets, ethereum-wallet-dapp

After adding several contracts from the Ropsten testnet to `WATCH CONTRACT` and tokens to `WATCH TOKEN`, I'd like to remove the contracts from displaying on [wallet.ethereum.org](http://wallet.ethereum.org).  Is there a way?

Comment: See https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/2103/how-to-remove-custom-tokens-from-mist and https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/2682/how-do-you-delete-remove-hide-contracts-from-ethereum-wallet-aka-mist?rq=1

Comment: @BokkyPooBah Thanks for your reply, but your links pertain to the Ethereum Wallet (Mist). My question pertains to wallet.ethereum.org, a browser-based wallet.

Comment: You are quite right. You may want to try clearing your browser history. And access your web browser JavaScript console and execute the command `localStorage.clear();`