# How to remove The DAO contract from Ethereum Wallet (Mist) watch list as it is freezing?

Tags: mist, ethereum-wallet-dapp, bug, the-dao

I added The DAO to my Mist watch list, but as many people I experienced freeze of the wallet since. I would like to remove this contract that probably generates too much transactions to watch but as UI freezes when I try to access it, I can't.

Is there another way to remove the watched contact, perhaps by modifying a file manually? Thanks.

Comment: Not sure but could it be possible to solve this through Geth rather than using the full Mist UI? Perhaps someone could elaborate on that if it is indeed possible. I wonder if it's possible to use this solution with Geth rather than Mist: http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/2103/how-to-remove-custom-tokens-from-mist?rq=1

Comment: I'm not sure the list of contracts that you watch in mist is related to geth. It's more probably a mist config or database, but geth only manages blockchain and requests as I can't remember a "watch contract" function in geth.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

### Trashcan

Click on the contract you want to delete. On the contract page, hover over the name. You see a trashcan. Click on this to remove the contract.

EDIT: As noted by @Vesa, you may not be able to access the contract as Mist freezes. What OS and version of Mist are you using. 
I have had some problems with Ethereum Wallet 0.7.2 that are not present in 0.6.2 - Try running this older version to remove your contract.

### Manual Deletion

In the Ethereum Wallet (Mist) menu, click on Develop -> Toggle Developer Tools -> Wallet UI. Click on the Console tab.

Enter `CustomContracts.find().fetch()` in the console, finding the `_id` of the Custom Contract, then entering the command `CustomContracts.remove({your Custom Contract _id})`.

This is similar to removing custom tokens in Mist - see the screens in [How to remove custom tokens from mist?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/2103/how-to-remove-custom-tokens-from-mist) as linked by `@Vesa`.

---

#### UPDATE 18 May 2016

A new version of the Ethereum Wallet (Mist) 0.7.4 (Beta 18) is available from https://github.com/ethereum/mist/releases/. Note that you should remove The DAO contract from your watchlist if you experience any freezes.

> If you are watching The DAO we recommend you stop watching it for now, at least while it's so popular. You can still send ether to it, if that's your intention. On our testings, even if the performance has improved, watching the DAO still hangs the wallet occasionally.

If you still cannot remove the The DAO contract from Mist due to the freezing, consider downgrading Mist to 0.6.2, remove the contract, then use the latest version.

---

#### UPDATE 29 May 2016

If you leave Ethereum Wallet running for a few hours after you experience a freezing issue, Ethereum Wallet will catch up with the event log entries it is due to receive from `geth`, and once again Ethereum Wallet will become responsive to your actions.

---

#### UPDATE 23 Jul 2016

My Ethereum Wallet application kept freezing even after removing The DAO contact and re-installing The DAO contract.

I renamed my `~/.config/Mist` directory:

```
cd ~/.config
mv Mist Mist_pre_20160723
```

I started Ethereum Wallet and reinstalled The DAO contract using the instructions from [How to add and watch the DAO contract](https://daowiki.atlassian.net/wiki/display/DAO/How+to+add+and+watch+the+DAO+contract) .

Ethereum Wallet is now working smoothly.

I then removed my old `~/.config/Mist_pre_20160723` directory.

The Ethereum Wallet config directories are:

- On Linux, `~/.config/Mist`
- On OS X, `~/Library/Application Support/Mist`
- On Windows, `C:\Users\<name>\AppData\Roaming\Mist`

Comment: How can he do any of that if the wallet is frozen and unresponsive? Ah, I guess the menu bar remains unfrozen, right?

Comment: After some long time the freeze stopped and I tried both solutions but for the first, the trash icon does nothing and for the second, console throws this error : CustomContacts.find().fetch()
VM1219:2 Uncaught ReferenceError: CustomContacts is not defined

Comment: Could you please add screen prints of the `fetch()`, `remove()` and the error to your question? Worst case, remove the Mist config files and have a fresh start. On Linux it is $HOME/.config/Mist . Rename first and then delete if successful.

Comment: @BokkyPooBah I'm on Mac but it's almost the same except the path. However, I would like to be sure not to have to download the whole blockchain again. By the way, can I bachup the chain data folder and reuse it with a fresh mist install to avoid starting from block zero?

Comment: Yup, you can copy the chain data folder.

Comment: hi, I updated to Ethereum Wallet 0.7.3 (I'm on mac) and it now freeze less so I am able to access the contract screen and I see the trash icon. But when clicking on it, a confirmation dialog asks me to type the contract name, which I named "The DAO" to confirm deletion. And this doesn't do anything.

Comment: Thanks for this update, I downloaded the latest wallet ans I will give it a try asap.

Comment: I'm so dumb... I copied and past your command line "CustomContacts.find().fetch()" without noticing an "r" was missing. The right command is "CustomContracts.find().fetch()". Removing the contract then works fine. However, removing it using the trash icon still does nothing at all (not even a console error log)