# Mist 0.8.1 crash under Windows 10

Tags: mist, windows, bug

I've just downloaded Mist 0.8.1 under Windows 10 (fully up to date). It was working at first, but is now crashing after the sync.

I followed these steps, maybe something here munged the preferences?

1. Downloaded and ran Mist 0.8.1. I saw the new announcement but didn't click anything.
2. At that point, I realized I wanted to back up my wallet before proceeding. So I clicked close (X) and opened v 0.7.6. I went to Backup > Accounts and made a copy of everything.
3. Closed v0.7.6 and re-opened v0.8.1., and clicked Yes for the DAO fork. Mist was having a lot of trouble syncing: it would say it found 2 peers, then 3 peers, then they would disappear. But after a while it synced. In the meantime, I was able to launch the application and see the new interface.
4. After a long sync, I don't know if I quit or the application crashed. However now, when I open it and click Launch the Application before it syncs, it crashes, and if I wait to let it sync, it crashes when done syncing. So I can't get to the interface.

I found the log, but I wouldn't know what to look for.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to report this on [Github](https://github.com/ethereum/mist/issues) to make sure the developers see it. You could also try the [Gitter](https://gitter.im/ethereum/mist) chat room for Mist.

With the upcoming hard fork, they are probably scrambling to make last minute fixes.

Comment: Thanks - I tried to submit a bug on Github but don't have permissions to create a new issue. Will try on Gitter.

Comment: @Jph108 If you were able to fix your problem please update your issue with the resolution. It may help others who are having the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

See "UPDATE 23/07/2016" in [How to remove The DAO contract from Ethereum Wallet (Mist) watch list as it is freezing?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/3794/how-to-remove-the-dao-contract-from-ethereum-wallet-mist-watch-list-as-it-is-f).

I renamed my Ethereum Wallet configuration directory and it has fixed all my freezing & updating issues (so far).