# I load Mist, it connects to nodes, then when I "Launch App" it just closes

Tags: mist

If I let it sync instead of launching, it just closes when it's done syncing. I did not see an answer to this problem in the only prior thread I could find.

Thank you

Comment: You are trying it with testnet or mainnet?

Comment: I'm not sure. I just downloaded the wallet through the main ethereum site

Comment: In the Mist, Check the network under the tab "Develop".

Comment: I cannot check it because it does not even load. Only the initial small screen opens while it connects to nodes, then if I launch the app, it just closes.

Comment: May be it can help you http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/7146/mist-0-8-1-crash-under-windows-10?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

The same thing was happening to me, for the past 48 hours or so on Windows 7.  Mist would display it's splash screen, sync the blockchain, and then crash before opening its UI.  There wasn't anything helpful in the node.logs, and running Geth in the command line seemed fine.

There's nothing elegant about this solution, but it did fix the problem I was having: I deleted the entire contents of /%AppData%/Roaming/Mist and ran Mist again

Do back it up if you try this, just in case.