# MyEtherWallet The DAO withdraw is stuck, can I continue manually?

Tags: ether, tokens, the-dao, myetherwallet, thedao-refund

I believe the withdrawal process for my test amount of DAO to be withdrawn to Ether got stuck after the approval function, it now shows 0 amount of DAO but Ether didn't increase.
Can I manually resume, i.e. invoke the next function or is it going to be more complicated than that?

This is the address in question: [0xC4Da809d8071704F01B403b781877E4A0Feef01D](https://etherscan.io/address/0xC4Da809d8071704F01B403b781877E4A0Feef01D)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This transaction](https://etherscan.io/tx/0xf8176a25075c964ef40bb81e4991de5f37ace36488c1b9c051dad21e01479119) shows that you have successfully called `TheDAO.approve(...)`, the first step described in [How do I convert my The DAO tokens into ethers using the withdrawal contract after the hard fork?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/7204/how-do-i-convert-my-the-dao-tokens-into-ethers-using-the-withdrawal-contract-aft).

What is remaining is to call the second step `theDAOWithdrawal.withdraw(...)`.

You cannot manually resume with MyEtherWallet as it executes both `TheDAO.approve(...)` and `theDAOWithdrawal.withdraw(...)` in the one go.

The `TheDAO.approve(...)` function can however be called more than once, so you can just re-run the MyEtherWallet **Withdraw your DAO Tokens for ETH**. You will end up paying ~ 0.00095508 Ether ($0.01) extra as this is the transaction fee for calling `TheDAO.approve(...)` a second time.

Or if you have the Ethereum Wallet installed and synced, you can just run the **Execute The Withdrawal Contract Function** section under **Withdrawal Method 2 - Ethereum Wallet** described in [How do I convert my The DAO tokens into ethers using the withdrawal contract after the hard fork?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/7204/how-do-i-convert-my-the-dao-tokens-into-ethers-using-the-withdrawal-contract-aft).

What I don't understand is why MyEtherWallet only executed the first `TheDAO.approve(...)` part and not the second `theDAOWithdrawal.withdraw(...)` part. The `generateAndSendWithdrawTx` function in https://www.myetherwallet.com/js/etherwallet-master.js executes both parts in the same function.

Comment: Yep that I didn't understand either.
Thanks! I shall try again and then report on the outcome, should be able to afford the 0.01$ ;)

Comment: It seems that myetherwallet is experiencing some issues, tried with different browsers, and the site is sometimes (partly) down. I'll wait for now or try with Mist

Comment: `@tayvano` on thedao.slack.com posted "just fixed mew error"

Comment: Alright, did it again, now it worked, thanks you guys!

Comment: Is there something broken again? I tried to withdraw the dao to eth. But nothing happened. https://etherscan.io/tx/0x40314b5b2377c13f4071ed2f4bb68329bf384987134db11a7dd460764676492e
There is only `TheDAO.approve(...)`