# Withdrawing ETH from DAOs on Poloniex

Tags: ether, tokens, the-dao, poloniex, thedao-refund

Guys I really need your help. I had purchased DAO tokens initially from this address: 0xA54367910EFEBA7B03B0aEcd8fFa62181b612038. I had 9000 tokens. When the attack happened I transfered them to Poloniex wanting to sell them, but I never did. Now when the fork happened, I wanted to withdraw my DAO tokens and convert them back to ETH. I followed this [guide](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/7204/how-do-i-convert-my-the-dao-tokens-into-ethers-using-the-withdrawal-contract-aft/7205#7205)

After making all the steps I somehow see 38,000 ETH in my DAO contract in the Wallet, a lot of transactions saying "The DAO - Token transfer" with some huge amount of DAO tokens and no ETH refunded to me.

I really am confused what is going on and scared that I might have done something irrevirsible. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I somehow feel that withdrawing those DAO tokens from Poloniex to my wallet didn't give me my original DAO tokens but some others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checking [your account](http://etherscan.io/address/0xA54367910EFEBA7B03B0aEcd8fFa62181b612038), there was a [transaction](http://etherscan.io/tx/0x29ebe0ff11023a669606039e3b119200dfb3e79b12496541794d171789e9c2a9) to `TheDAO.approve(...)` the transfer of the DAO tokens from The DAO contract into the Withdrawal contract. But there is no corresponding `Withdrawal.withdraw()` transaction to transfer the ETH from the Withdrawal contract into your account.

When viewing your account, the Token Tracker, [View Token Balance] dropdown shows 0 DAOs are associated with your account.

You will need to transfer your DAOs still left on your Poloniex account back to your account, then run the `approve(...)` and `withdraw()` functions to convert the DAO tokens back to ETH.

The 38,442.565926800000000001 ETH in the DAO contract in the Wallet is just the balance of ETH owned by The DAO contract and has nothing to do with your personal account.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @BokkyPooBah. I withdrew my DAO tokens from Poloniex and transfered them to (and here is what I think I did wrong...) to this address: 0xBB9bc244D798123fDe783fCc1C72d3Bb8C189413  which seems to be The DAO itself ? Does that mean I withdrew them to unexisting address? I really feel super bad right now and can't even focus writing this. My Ether wallet address is: 0xA54367910EFEBA7B03B0aEcd8fFa62181b612038  and my Poloniex DAO address is: 0x77b449a482820de36e99e672476d4e9795f6dd49

Comment: Ouchh. You have sent your DAOs to The DAO contract. I don't know if it will be possible to get it back.

Comment: I don't really know what to do then. I`m noob with ETH and crypto in general and I know I shouldn't have done this when I was almost sleeping. I don't know anyone who can help me and you are the only person that replied here. If you help me contact Slock.it owners and see if it's possible to get it like that, I promise to pay you generously from the DAO tokens I owned. Please write me on petrov.marin@gmail.com if you want.

Comment: I've asked @GriffGreen your question on https://forum.daohub.org/t/how-to-get-the-additional-refund-extra-balance-for-the-dao-to-eth-withdrawal/6274/14 .