# Help with Withdrawal of ETH from TheDAO Withdrawal Contract

Tags: ether, dao

I obviously screwed up when attempting to convert TheDAO to ETH using the DAO withdrawal contract.

I sent my DAO tokens to the withdrawal contract address http://etherscan.io/tx/0x7f5674b1ab461f99a0fae9fa00453c7cf312c2c2e02aaf7d32260162d75386b3 and they show as sent to the contract, however I cannot figure out how to withdraw ETH from that as I didn't send them in an 'approved' transaction as the instructions say to do.

Any help would be appreciated.

The problem I am having is that my DAO tokens are now at the DAO contract address and I am unable to withdraw the ETH from the contract after sending it my tokens.  I cannot go back and redo the steps to correct it or follow the tutorial on how to convert the DAO tokens to ETH using the contract because I don't have the tokens anymore.

I am unsure who to contact or how to get the tokens back.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I convert my The DAO tokens into ethers using the withdrawal contract after the hard fork?](http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/7204/how-do-i-convert-my-the-dao-tokens-into-ethers-using-the-withdrawal-contract-aft)

Comment: This is not a duplicate.  I already read through that question and it had no information on how to resolve my issue.  I am still unable to withdraw the ETH from the contract after sending my DAO.

Comment: I have the same issue.  Did you make any progress or get an answer?