# Question about updating Ethereum Wallet 0.5.2 to latest version: Will this affect my ETH balance and DAO wallet address

Tags: wallets

I need to update my ethereum wallet from 0.5.2 to the latest version (OSX), because I wish to withdraw my DAO tokens that are attached to an address in the wallet.

The wallet contains ETH that were obtained prior to the fork.

Will the current ETH balance be affected by updating the wallet?

If I send that ETH (pre-fork) to an exchange like Poloniex, will they be recognized as ETH or ETC?

Will the address remain the same after updating the wallet?

thank you!

Comment: You only need the private key of your account. Backup the account file, update the wallet and import the account.

Answer (score 1):

Like Sebi said, export, then import the private key.

I believe you know this post to withdraw the DAO tokens [How do I convert my The DAO tokens into ethers using the withdrawal contract after the hard fork?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/7204/how-do-i-convert-my-the-dao-tokens-into-ethers-using-the-withdrawal-contract-aft)

However, if you make any transfer it will be both an ETH and an ETC transfer because your transaction will find its way on the other fork and will be accepted as valid on both. Look up "replay attack".

So before you make any transfer, be sure to read about the splitter contract procedure. When splitting, you have to use the balance you had *before* you withdrew your DAO tokens (minus the gas of the withdrawal), in effect, your balance in ETC after the withdrawal, because that is the minimum balance agreed between the 2 forks.

Example with silly values:

```
Pre-fork                Post-fork                  Post-withdrawal     Post-splitter
                                                   (if 0.1 for gas)    (if 0.1 for gas)
Addr1: 10 ETH + 1 DAO   ETH-fork  10 ETH + 1 DAO   10.9 ETH            1 ETH
Addr2:                                                                 9.8 ETH
_
Addr1:                  ETC-fork  10 ETC + 1 DAO   9.9 ETC + 1 DAO     1 DAO
Addr3:                                                                 9.8 ETC
```

So after the split:

- the 1 ETH in your address1 is safe from replay because it has 0 in ETC fork
- the 9.8 ETH in your address2 is safe because it has 0 in ETC
- the 9.8 ETC in your address3 is safe because it has 0 in ETH

https://blog.ethereum.org/2016/07/26/onward_from_the_hard_fork/

https://steemit.com/ethereum/@pauls/ethereum-fork-step-by-step-guide-to-safely-splitting-your-eth-etc