# Blockchain syncs in Mist, but not in Geth?

Tags: go-ethereum, mist, blockchain, windows

I'm trying to mine. When I try syncing in Geth, all my handshakes fail and I cannot add peers. My port 30303 is open and syncing still doesn't occur with the --nat=none flag. Mist syncs no problem. I'm using Windows right now because I'm having trouble getting Rx 480 drivers working in Debian. Here is my command prompt output:

```
C:\Program Files\Geth>geth --rpc --nat=none --verbosity 5 I0922 04:01:19.690683    1208 backend.go:256] Protocol Version: 60, Network Id: 0 I0922 04:01:19.690683    1208 backend.go:266] Blockchain DB Version: 3 I0922 04:01:19.691686    1208 statedb.go:232] (+) b9c015918bdaba24b4ff057a92a3873d6eb201be I0922 04:01:19.692688    1208 statedb.go:232] (+) 6c386a4b26f73c802f34673f7248bb118f97424a I0922 04:01:19.692688    1208 statedb.go:232] (+) cd2a3d9f938e13cd947ec05abc7fe734df8dd826 I0922 04:01:19.692688    1208 statedb.go:232] (+) e6716f9544a56c530d868e4bfbacb172315bdead I0922 04:01:19.692688    1208 statedb.go:232] (+) 0000000000000000000000000000000000000001 I0922 04:01:19.692688    1208 statedb.go:232] (+) 0000000000000000000000000000000000000002 I0922 04:01:19.692688    1208 statedb.go:232] (+) 0000000000000000000000000000000000000003 I0922 04:01:19.692688    1208 statedb.go:232] (+) 0000000000000000000000000000000000000004 I0922 04:01:19.692688    1208 statedb.go:232] (+) 1a26338f0d905e295fccb71fa9ea849ffa12aaf4 I0922 04:01:19.692688    1208 statedb.go:232] (+) dbdbdb2cbd23b783741e8d7fcf51e459b497e4a6 I0922 04:01:19.692688    1208 statedb.go:232] (+) e4157b34ea9615cfbde6b4fda419828124b70c78 I0922 04:01:19.692688    1208 statedb.go:232] (+) 2ef47100e0787b915105fd5e3f4ff6752079d5cb I0922 04:01:19.693690    1208 chain_manager.go:258] Last block (#0) fd4af92a79c7fc2fd8bf0d342f2e832e1d4f485c85b9152d2039e03bc604fdca TD=131072 I0922 04:01:19.693690    1208 statedb.go:232] (+) 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000 I0922 04:01:19.693690    1208 state_object.go:241] 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000: gas (+ 3141592) I0922 04:01:19.693690    1208 state_object.go:197] 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000: #0 1500000000000000000 (+ 1500000000000000000) I0922 04:01:19.696698    1208 cmd.go:148] Starting Geth/v0.9.26/windows/go1.4.2 I0922 04:01:19.696698    1208 server.go:293] Starting Server I0922 04:01:19.704719    1208 udp.go:189] Listening, enode://ad39a762dca79653988a8b4e3015c7e82bee52b03b36d13b3e1c595c0a2849a203da3d39ddc109b32abfe5421650eecfd717b2ef69b55f41498d10b99307d250@[::]:30303 I0922 04:01:19.704719    1208 backend.go:477] Server started I0922 04:01:19.704719    1208 server.go:530] Listening on [::]:30303 I0922 04:01:19.705722    1208 table.go:279] Seeding network with enode://002d253340adf5d01aa257e9ae20a6651fbe57702b6847c2ff4355717681d1f6ed7bb5fca1f620896c1636293ab81e1f32ba9343feea45da618f798b9c7592e5@104.131.91.143:30303 I0922 04:01:19.705722    1208 table.go:279] Seeding network with enode://004746ebb4bcf5bc49d7c267935af00d0dc0dc64c9db63e1b034e8e9d47197b4cc951299fdcb50418babb5c2bb4d8f4079ac71e7999d9f78f68ff8814361fd92@77.120.98.234:30303 I0922 04:01:19.705722    1208 table.go:279] Seeding network with enode://005b5d9f1180dccdf9ae26db2be5343c7836d715314a9097f435e959ce1853130adf2bbbf2f1a79c2ec92d531e8fa2b6a7c5a204e7e435e8a34a827df493bad1@45.63.86.233:30303 I0922 04:01:19.705722    1208 table.go:279] Seeding network with enode://0094142aa8868e5871b81544ecb1239dd0bc09c2fedbd7faea55715d7dc5e6a37476b42d5fc704ab6ac1902188c94462eeed5823a2d9f5b2be5dddd7e77d4554@59.149.136.210:30303?discport=1101 I0922 04:01:19.705722    1208 table.go:279] Seeding network with enode://00aa2772e8a4556531f43bfecea53b25c24a8383cc0d4a805d071438ad1b49e014ac3a8b72ced59d984d0beac0e5796ad18226cc4436a38bd2a07505f2bda95e@206.255.93.25:30303?discport=30659 I0922 04:01:19.705722    1208 table.go:279] Seeding network with enode://00aed81a40d123e22e0f780f3d5a85a34ca84a630d03c6928621dd252db4e4f1034ff1e14184694a5e57f267dcca3f3d429fa0bd7ea85e0165373a38d3287941@92.51.166.201:30303 I0922 04:01:19.705722    1208 table.go:279] Seeding network with enode://00af8248d908e2669a2692980ae084981ca7021e09e124cb7c6b792e1b5ede423f1d61e3d61f28e0fd0a58ba2a7c4fa880b60c766c33dcc55a2a3c71f34a8e52@173.192.160.221:30303 I0922 04:01:19.705722    1208 table.go:279] Seeding network with enode://00b2c3c9a17b530da3f9cb5a14393aff58530f619b551b2028ffd4402e115092a329cdd76da21f19bc76c2aa937c24a5ca5e1984de9db8209507b4627297d238@123.56.49.100:30303 I0922 04:01:19.705722    1208 table.go:279] Seeding network with enode://00c33747a9e57d21eba29ec6c50b5900f73e1d9d92eab2f980296ac6c0e53dcfb556cd488e260f574a5922a2e6d916e4c1490dbd6919ea6fc94beeb393241191@114.55.224.76:30303 I0922 04:01:19.705722    1208 table.go:279] Seeding network with enode://01178960a1da0ee9b2e9802686c871f1aab758898a6755b19d3b68cd4fc1685e7a9332ee87d22b07cb2ac67a444f689c3f912bb2c29173928e2980d1ab8bffe4@188.213.173.170:30303 I0922 04:01:19.850080    1208 server.go:550] Accepted conn
52.197.114.185:42550 I0922 04:01:19.862115    1208 server.go:574] inbound conn 52.197.114.185:42550 faild enc handshake: could not decrypt auth message (ecies: invalid public key) I0922 04:01:20.581366 1208 server.go:550] Accepted conn 94.125.189.5:54237 I0922 04:01:20.594433    1208 server.go:574] inbound conn 94.125.189.5:54237 faild enc handshake: could not decrypt auth message (ecies: invalid public key) I0922 04:01:20.662413    1208 server.go:550] Accepted conn
159.122.239.115:34231 I0922 04:01:20.675859    1208 server.go:574] inbound conn 159.122.239.115:34231 faild enc handshake: could not decrypt auth message (ecies: invalid public key) I0922 04:01:20.766422 1208 server.go:550] Accepted conn 190.217.6.5:65023 I0922 04:01:20.920987    1208 cmd.go:60] Shutting down (interrupt) ... I0922 04:01:20.933044    1208 server.go:603] inbound conn 698f40d3dbfa0b75
190.217.6.5:65023 failed checkpoint addpeer: server stopped I0922 04:01:20.948324    1208 handler.go:128] Stopping ethereum protocol handler... I0922 04:01:20.948324    1208 handler.go:138] Ethereum protocol handler stopped I0922 04:01:20.952296    1208 chain_manager.go:514] Chain manager stopped I0922 04:01:20.952296    1208 transaction_pool.go:276] TX Pool stopped I0922 04:01:20.952296    1208 backend.go:645] Automatic pregeneration of ethash DAG OFF (ethash dir: C:\Users\admin\AppData\Ethash) I0922 04:01:20.966334    1208 database.go:78] flushed and closed db: C:\Users\admin\AppData\Roaming\Ethereum\blockchain I0922 04:01:20.982375    1208 database.go:78] flushed and closed db: C:\Users\admin\AppData\Roaming\Ethereum\state I0922 04:01:20.990396    1208 database.go:78] flushed and closed db: C:\Users\admin\AppData\Roaming\Ethereum\extra
```

Peers is continuously at 0 for Geth command line. Why would Mist sync when Geth could not? How else can I get Geth to sync?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two possibilities as listed below, but most likely the first one. Wait until the newly patched binaries are available, then upgrade.

### 1. The Ethereum network is currently being DDOS-ed.

https://twitter.com/JohnLilic/status/778963611448250368

https://blog.ethereum.org/2016/09/22/ethereum-network-currently-undergoing-dos-attack/

Here's my Ethereum Wallet indicator showing that `geth` is failing to keep up with processing the blocks. The reason is that the attacker is sending many low gas cost transactions that performs a lot of blockchain data reading (disk activity).

[image]

And here are the next steps planned by the Ethereum Developers to deal with these kind of issues - https://blog.ethereum.org/2016/09/22/transaction-spam-attack-next-steps/

### 2. You are running an older version of `geth` from the command line

To check (I'm using OS/X but Windows should be similar):

```
Iota:mac-x64 user$ pwd
/Applications/Ethereum Wallet.app/Contents/nodes/geth/mac-x64
# Current version of geth packaged with Ethereum Wallet
Iota:mac-x64 user$ ./geth version
Geth
Version: 1.4.12-stable-421df866
Protocol Versions: [63 62]
Network Id: 1
Go Version: go1.7
OS: darwin
GOPATH=
GOROOT=/usr/local/go

# Older version of geth with the recent bug
Iota:mac-x64 user$ geth version
Geth
Version: 1.4.11-stable-fed692f6
Protocol Versions: [63 62]
Network Id: 1
Go Version: go1.6
OS: darwin
GOPATH=
GOROOT=/usr/local/Cellar/go/1.6/libexec
```

Comment: I just re-installed Geth yesterday, so version is not the issue. Any theories about why Mist was able to sync? Thanks!

Comment: The --cache 2014 flag provided in one of your links did the trick. Thanks.

Comment: Hi, is this still going on?  I'm trying to sort out my DAO tokens, and not having a lot of luck.  Am I too late?  Or what?  Thanks anyway, sorry for the noob question.

Comment: Yes. Still going on. There is a hard-fork scheduled for tomorrow (Tuesday) - see https://blog.ethereum.org/2016/10/13/announcement-imminent-hard-fork-eip150-gas-cost-changes/ . Download the latest binaries, wait until the network settles down after the hard fork, then try again. There is a time limit for the DAO to ETC chain of a few months. There is no time limit for the DAO to ETH and extraBalance withdrawal.