# Trying to get a refund from my DAO results in "out of gas"

Tags: parity, the-dao, out-of-gas, thedao-refund

I'm trying to get the ETH refund from my DAO, following [the instructions here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/7205/581) (but with Parity 1.4.4).

The approve transaction is [here](https://etherscan.io/tx/0xc66817cdf4349fc7db9c3a03529d861827267b28753a62f7968f12ef25141f67).

But I already tried to send the withdraw transaction twice, in both cases it's out of gas, why? The attempts:

- [1st](https://etherscan.io/tx/0xfddf9d338cabd9bb76d7033427f2d57189dd2d68b47a5a3853a652e174d85e4b)
- [2nd](https://etherscan.io/tx/0xefb4d651e1a924b883514cce3c11c03b9d8d0fd0c6ed778571a0c430ed9278cb)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried redownloading the blockchain? I know there have been some anomalies after the state clearing; all my problems were fixed when I did this yesterday?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Alexey's pointers about Parity were not accurate enough: at the time of this writing, the feature has just been recently [implemented](https://github.com/ethcore/parity/issues/3510) in master branch (after 1.4.6 is released), and I just compiled parity myself because I couldn't wait for the release of 1.4.7 to test it.

The version is labeled as "1.5.0-beta" and in fact includes GAS editing when exeucting a contract. I added double the gas that it was estimating, and finally the withdrawal of ETH from DAO was [successful](https://etherscan.io/tx/0xd79edb4d7d14835777a9774be0696ae3e06054c1fe56b461606278c55a333e06).

This actually means that Parity is not accurate enough when estimating the gas for the execution of a contract, so I've raised a bug [here](https://github.com/ethcore/parity/issues/3808).

Answer (score 1):

The numbers in the approve and the balance of your account look correct. But it looks like you are simply not giving the transaction enough gas to execute. You are giving about 76k gas, but this transaction needs around 412k. Try to give more and it will succeed.

EDIT:
I have asked on the Parity gitter, and Gavin Wood said that it is not currently possible to increase gasLimit from the Parity UI, but it will land in their next release.

EDIT2:
Version 1.4.6 of Parity has "Advanced sending options" tick box that allows you to increase the gas limit

Comment: how? parity doesn't let me specify gas when executing a contract

Comment: I posted a question on the parity gitter, could not find such an option myself

Comment: thanks for re-editing the answer but the "advanced sending options" feature is still (even in v.1.4.6) an option that only exists in the UI to send transactions, not in the one to execute contracts. I recommend you to test hings yourself before trying to answer on StackExchange. (See my own answer.)

Comment: you know, I tried to help as much as I can, and yes, I made a mistake and did not check everything. But I spent a fair bit of time on this already did not expect an annoyed response.

Comment: annoyed response? I don't know why did you get such an impression, I'm just stating the facts :)

Comment: Ok, I am sorry then. I thought you were annoyed when writing "I recommend you test things yourself before trying to answer on StackExchange".

Answer (score 0):

It is not an out of gas failure.
Look at the [vmtrace](https://etherscan.io/vmtrace?txhash=0xfddf9d338cabd9bb76d7033427f2d57189dd2d68b47a5a3853a652e174d85e4b&type=parity) logs.
It says `"error": "Bad jump destination"`

Comment: and what does that mean?