# Does the ETC whitehat withdraw contract still work?

Tags: synchronization

Apparently the withdraw period has ended.  https://blog.bity.com/2017/04/03/the-whitehat-withdrawal-contract-distribution-period-is-now-reaching-its-end/

Can someone confirm this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I convert my The DAO tokens into ethers using the withdrawal contract after the hard fork?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/7204/how-do-i-convert-my-the-dao-tokens-into-ethers-using-the-withdrawal-contract-aft)

Comment: I've retracted my close vote as it's not obvious from the most recent update to the accepted answer on that post (end of March) that the instructions still work.

Comment: Correct, I don't want to waste my time going through the process if the contract is already expired

Comment: but if you look here: https://gastracker.io/addr/0x9f5304da62a5408416ea58a17a92611019bd5ce3  It seems that there is still outgoing ETC from the contract