# TheDAO old ERC20 Token Swap

Tags: myetherwallet

I was looking at my old Ethereum wallet and I saw that I have some of the old TheDAO tokens.  Is it still possible to swap them back into ETH?  If so, can someone please explain to me in very simple, caveman style, instructions?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I convert my The DAO tokens into ethers using the withdrawal contract after the hard fork?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/7204/how-do-i-convert-my-the-dao-tokens-into-ethers-using-the-withdrawal-contract-aft)

Comment: I’m also trying to do this.. can’t find any answer :(